# Registercollection open generic type

Tags: c#, generics, simple-injector

Is the following possible with [Simple Injector **4**](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/4.0/quickstart.html)?

```
var types = container.GetTypesToRegister(typeof(IFoo<>), assemblies);
container.RegisterCollection(typeof(IFoo<>), types);
```

with

```
public interface IFoo<T> where T : IBar { ... }
```

and

```
public interface IBar { ... }
```

and in the assembly similar types can be found like the following:

```
public class Foo : IFoo<FooBar> { ... }
```

where

```
public class FooBar : IBar { ... }
```

The container verifies this registration. But when I do

```
container.GetAllInstances<IFoo<IBar>>();
```

Then the result is empty.
My intention is to inject the following:

```
IEnumerable<IFoo<IBar>> foos
```

which I expect to return all closed type implementations of `IFoo<>` where the closed generic parameter is an implementation of `IBar`.

Also another point is that whenever I want to write a unit test for the service that consumes `IEnumerable<IFoo<IBar>>`, I'm trying to mock this with the following:

```
IEnumerable<IFoo<IBar>> collection = new[] { new Foo() };
new ConsumerService(collection);
```

Here the compiler has a hard time to convert the type `Foo` to `IFoo<IBar>`, which I think I understand (not sure..). But what I don't understand is that how Simple Injector would instantiate the types in the collection?

Comment: What is it you like to achieve? From the supplied code I don't really understand what it is you exactly want. The open generic parameter is always `IBar` so why do you want to get all isntances of IFoo<IBar>. Seems you just wanting to have ALL implementations and still you want them to be generic..?

Comment: You second question demonstrates the problem Simple Injector has here! Remember [Constraints are not part of the signature](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature/)

Comment: Thanks @Ric.Net for the reminder. Indeed, I think I tried to make generic parameter constraints part of my signature and that should be avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to achieve what you want, you will have to make your `IFoo<T>` interface variant.

The reason you get an empty list is because `IFoo<IBar>` is not assignable from `IFoo<FooBar>`. Try it out yourself: the C# compiler will not permit you to cast `Foo` to `IFoo<IBar>`.

To achieve this you will have to make `IFoo<T>` covariant. In other words, you need to define the interface as follows:

```
public interface IFoo<out T> { }
```

After you done this, you'll see that Simple Injector automatically resolves all instances for you as you'd expect.

Whether however it is useful for you to have an `out` type argument is a different question. One that I cannot answer, given the abstract description you gave.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why covariant will work and contravariant won't? I tested it with contravariant and that does not work. I'm having a hard time to understand where the difference is?

Comment: Say that a method returns `string`, a caller who needs `object` can work just fine. Obviously, when a method returns `object` there is no guarantee that it returns a string, so the caller can't call it back to string. This is exactly how covariance works.

Comment: You can cast an `IEnumerable<string>` to `IEnumerable<object>` and therefore you can cast an `IFoo<FooBar>` to `IFoo<IBar>` in case `T` is `out`, but not the other way around.

Comment: Thanx, Make sense. Probably good to add to the documentation. The documentation now only handles the `in` keyword

Comment: Well, perhaps. Although many developers struggle with this, it is however rudimentary C# and .NET functionality and much has been written about this on MSDN and elsewhere. It's not Simple Injector's job to teach developers C# though, so I'm not that eager to add a complete documentation about this in the docs.